# How to build ch341.ko usb-serial driver for android?

Tags: android, linux, kernel

we require the ch341.ko module on our android device.

This is an optional module that has been included in the kernel source since 2.4.x (maybe 2.3.x).

```
The source is located under (kernel)/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c

    I endevoured to learn how to build modules, then found it was already in the source so no need for makefiles and the like, then endevoured to find how to crosscompile the linux source with the ch341 option to add it to the device.
```

1. Install the crosscompiler
   I gathered the first thing was to locate the correct cross compiler, so running `cat /proc/version` on from the adb shell yeilded:

   root@android:/ # cat /proc/version
       Linux version 3.0.8+ (android2@Linux) (gcc version 4.5.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010.09-50) ) #47 PREEMPT Mon Jul 9 16:32:14 CST 2012

   Downloaded and setup Sourcery G++ on version 50 on my Fedora 16 box. Then added the directory of to the PATH variable:

   EXPORT PATH=$PATH:(Path to installed CodeSourcery)/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin

   or manually add it in ~/.bash_profile:

   sudo gedit ~/.bash_profile

   Then update the PATH variable:

   source ~/.bash_profile
2. Download the Kernel Source -

   Trying to find the correct source can prove difficult, however knowing the device was an A10 most likely from Allwinner, I found the following git repository and also handy tutorial:

   https://github.com/amery/linux-allwinner

   http://rhombus-tech.net/allwinner_a10/kernel_compile/

   After installing git, cloning the tree I tried compiling against 2 branches:

   "allwinner-v3.0-android-v2" (The main one)

   "lichee-3.0.8-sun4i" (Which is more inline with my device)

   I cross-compiled with the following commands:

   make ARCH=arm sun4i_defconfig
       make ARCH=arm menuconfig
       make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- -j16 uImage modules
       make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- INSTALL_MOD_PATH=output modules_install

   After each compilation, I pushed the ch341.ko file to the device:

   adb push output/lib/modules/3.0.8+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.ko /mnt/sdcard/LKMz/ch341.ko

   Then tried insmod"

   adb shell
       root@android:/ # insmod /mnt/sdcard/LKMz/ch341.ko
       insmod: init_module '/mnt/sdcard/LKMz/ch341.ko' failed (Exec format error)

   dmesg returned:

   dmesg
       ch341: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout

   And trying with the -f (force) option:

   ./system/xbin/busybox insmod -f /mnt/sdcard/LKMz/ch341.ko
       insmod: can't insert '/mnt/sdcard/LKMz/ch341.ko': invalid module format

   So it appears that there is an issue with the version or the compile options I'm using to compile the source with.

   Does anybody have any suggestions on how to compile the ch341.ko module?

Answer (score 1):

turn off the CONFIG_MODVERSIONS and check if it works. If not, "dmesg" and check new errors.

check [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cn/linux/l-cn-kernelmodules/index.html) page, it may helps.